# How to get the context inside a mouse click listener

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio, developing in Java, I have the following (a somewhat minimized version of what I'm trying to do).

```
package com.example.japanesequiz;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] hiragana = {"あ", "か"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button generate = findViewById(R.id.generate);
        TextView questionText = findViewById(R.id.question_text);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);

        MainActivity ma_inst = this;

        generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int hir_index = rand.nextInt(2);
                questionText.setText(hiragana[hir_index]);

                RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton(ma_inst);
                rb1.setId(View.generateViewId());
                rb1.setText("Ah");
                radioGroup.addView(rb1);
                RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton(ma_inst);
                rb2.setId(View.generateViewId());
                rb2.setText("Ka");
                radioGroup.addView(rb2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The basic idea is that I want to have the main screen initially mostly blank, but with a button at the bottom.  When tapped, it eventually show some text and a radio button group. (I haven't yet fully built out the rest, of course.)

But at this stage what I expect when I launch the app is to see the mostly blank screen, and maybe if I tap the button it will generate some text and options (that then do nothing, further implementation to come).

But the app never launches.  Instead, Graddle finishes building, I get a terminal saying that it's launching the app, but it hangs and times out.

---

If I had to guess -- and this is a guess because I'm very new to Android development -- there is some issue with grabbing the `this` instance and then using it in the `OnClickListener`.  I'm not certain what the issue is, but it's the only thing I see here that looks fishy.  Also, I'm not sure how else one is supposed to add objects to the current activity from inside of the anonymous class passed into the `OnClickListener` since, there, a reference to `this` then refers to the anonymous inner class.

I know that it is possible to use a lambda instead, and that probably resolves the issue, but I want to really understand what's going on here, since it seems like it might be conceptually important for later development.

---

**My question**: If I have correctly understood this much, then how does a lambda get around this issue?  If I've not correctly understood then I'd appreciate any insight, thanks!

Comment: "If I have correctly understood this much" -- sorry, but no. "but it hangs and times out" -- can you explain in greater detail what you are seeing? And, are you getting any stack traces [in Logcat](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html)?

Comment: @CommonsWare It takes about 5 minutes to get an error message, so I'll run it again and post the trace.  In the mean time, I can maybe say a bit more about what I'm seeing.  When I run the simulator, it pops up with a blank Android home screen.  The terminal says "02/01 13:48:49: Launching 'app' on Pixel 4 API 30."  After about five minutes it gives red text saying that it timed out, trying to launch the app.  I'll be more detailed when it gives the error again.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah, when I finally went to the Logcat it shows that no device was connected.  I guess maybe I misunderstood that clicking the play button automatically booted up an emulator and ran the app -- when I boot the emulator first and then click play, it seems to work.  Sorry about that!  I think I see what's going on now, or at least, I'm on a better track to figure it out.

Comment: In principle, Android Studio should launch the emulator automatically if it is not already running and your desired emulator image is selected in the drop-down adjacent to the Run button in the toolbar. There may be some configuration issue that is precluding it, or perhaps there is a bug in Studio. There is nothing you can do in code that would block the emulator from launching AFAIK. You might have problems in the app once the emulator launches, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many questions in one question. First, let me try to answer your title question: "How to get context inside a mouse click listener":

There are many ways, but you can consider this one (your click lisener's onClick has the signature `void onClick(View view)`, hence you have access to view.

```
view.getContext()
```

Next, nothing wrong with these though you better migrate to view binding https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding as butterknife is deprecated officially

```
        Button generate = findViewById(R.id.generate);
        TextView questionText = findViewById(R.id.question_text);
```

Next, you don't really need this trick in order to get activity in your lambda:

```
MainActivity ma_inst = this;
```

Instead and if really needed, you can always do `Context context = MainActivity.this;`

Lastly, I think the issue `the app never launches` roots into something else not related with title question you posted, unfortunately.

Comment: Hah, right, "you have access to `view`"!  Duh, of course, I should have thought of that!  Thank you!